# Passing Pulumi S3 Bucket ID to AWS Lambda as a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pulumi

I would like to pass the S3 bucket ID as a parameter to AWS Lambda via Pulumi.
However, Pulumi passes this parameter `On Build`, so I obtain an Object reference in Lambda instead of the S3 path.

My code looks like this

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(resource_name="bucket", acl="private")
lambda_func = lambda_.Function("Function",
                               role=lambda_role.arn,
                               package_type="Image",
                               image_uri=docker.image_name,
                               image_config={"commands": ["api/main.handler"]},
                               vpc_config={"subnet_ids": private_subnet_ids,
                                           "security_group_ids": [internet_access.id],
                                          },
                               environment=lambda_.FunctionEnvironmentArgs(
                                               variables={"STORE_PATH": f"s3://s{bucket.id}/api"})
                               )
```

According to Pulumi [documentation](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/):

> Outputs that contain strings cannot be used directly in operations such as string concatenation.

So I've tried the recommended methods like:

```
bucket_url = Output.all(bucket.id).apply(lambda l: f"http://{l[0]}/")
```

Or

```
url = Output.concat("http://", bucket.id, "/")
```

Any help is welcomed. Thank you in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last method should work fine. Note that `bucket.id` is just the name of the bucket, you need to build S3 access URL with it, e.g.

```
url = Output.concat("https://", bucket.id, ".s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
# or url = Output.concat("s3://", bucket.id)
```

If this still doesn't do what you want, you could export the value of the `url` to see how it's wrong (or post the result to your question).

```
export('url', url)
```

Comment: I don't know what I was doing. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the environment variables field of the lambda function needs a string. We need to tell Pulumi to ensure that the bucket id has resolved (ie, the bucket is finish creating and the outputs have been returned)

If you pass the `Output.concat` to the lambda function like so, it works:

```py
lambda_func = aws.lambda_.Function(
    "function",
    runtime="python3.7",
    role=role.arn,
    handler="hello_world.handler",
    code=pulumi.AssetArchive({".": pulumi.FileArchive(".")}),
    environment=aws.lambda_.FunctionEnvironmentArgs(
        variables={"STORE_PATH": pulumi.Output.concat("s3://", bucket.id, "/")}
    ),
)
```

Comment: Would be great if you could accept the answer as per the SO guidelines